# Need ideas to manage query results (cursor) with inequality operations

Tags: google-app-engine, cursor, objectify, datastore

I understand that there's a [limitation with App Engine's datastore cursor](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/datastore/query-cursors#limitations_of_cursors)  I am curious how people manage to retrieve the result sets under this limitation.

My scenario is that I need to run a query with both the "or" operator and NOT_EQUAL multiple times.  However, since the cursor is null, I cannot retrieve the next set of records.

P.S.  I am using Objectify as well, but haven't found any documentation whether Objectify has a workaround.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

For queries with `NOT_EQUAL` you can drop that particular element from the query to make it cursor-capable and implement the equivalent check in the result entity processing code instead (i.e. skip processing the entity if the corresponding `EQUAL` condition is true, for example).

To address the `or` limitation you can perform multiple separate cursor-capable queries for each of the `or` elements and make the result entity processing code idempotent by either:

- tracking or flagging the processed entities to ensure that entities appearing in multiple of the separate query results are only processed once
- having processing code produce the same result even if an entity is processed multiple times

The 2 techniques can be combined if needed - as in your case.

Of course, they are neither as convenient nor as efficient as without the cursor limitation ;)